# Cron task problem

Tags: magento2, cron

Recently, I deleted my child theme created on the basis of blank and installed a new theme that I bought in the store. But I noticed that my previous theme still does cron tasks. Image.jpg is periodically created in **/ pub / static / frontend / Vegetus / vegetus_theme / ru_RU / Magento_Catalog / images / product / placeholder**.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How does a "theme" perform cron jobs?  This would be a module of some kind and the cron jobs are all listed in etc/crontab.xml or for a quick overview use magerun: `n98-magerun2 sys:cron:list`

Comment: Using n98-magerun2 sys: cron: list I found following cronjobs. 
http://prntscr.com/qbq4jd
Could they be the reason for the appearance of / pub / static / frontend / Vegetus / vegetus_theme / ru_RU / Magento_Catalog / images / product / placeholder / image.jpg ?
And how can I solve this problem using this information?